# Trigger.io Ajax request

Tags: ajax, http, httpwebrequest, trigger.io, simperium

I am trying to get Trigger.io to make an HTTP request to simperium (https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/)

My call looks like:

```
forge.request.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.simperium.com/1/app-id/somebucket/i/newitem?response=1',
  headers: {
  'X-Simperium-Token': "access-token",
},
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
  'test': 'test'
},
success: function (suc) {
  forge.logging.info(JSON.stringify(suc));
  // Upload complete - do nothing
},
error: function (err) {
  forge.logging.info(JSON.stringify(err));
  alert('Problem uploading the metadata');
}
});
```

However Trigger returns:

```
[FORGE] '{"type":"EXPECTED_FAILURE","message":"Error opening connection for ajax request"}'
```

What would be wrong with the call? Thanks.

UPDATE:

It looks like it works for retrieving objects but still not for updating/creating new. This works for obtaining an object:

```
forge.request.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.simperium.com/1/app-id/sample/i/object-id',
headers: {
  'X-Simperium-Token': "token",
},
type: 'GET',
success: function (suc) {
  forge.logging.info(JSON.stringify(suc));
  // Upload complete - do nothing
},
error: function (err) {
  forge.logging.info(JSON.stringify(err));
  alert('Problem uploading the metadata');
}
```

});

Comment: Can you post your permissions array from your src/config.json: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html#config. Also, what device or emulator are you testing on?

Comment: I've just added a bit more logging, so we'll have more info if you run into the problem from v1.4.27 onwards. In the meantime, see Amir's questions.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a super old question (almost 12 months!!). I'm checking open Simperium questions, and just wanted to ask you: are you still having any issues with the library?.

Thanks!